# Where to find Memory class shown in MSDN article?

Tags: c#

I would ask you in which library is the `Memory` class? I searched the msdn website in a special section, dynamic memory allocation ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/aa664786(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/aa664786%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)), but it shows only examples and not where the class.

Comment: The `Memory` class doesn't exist in .NET.  It is just an example class showing how to access OS heap functions in C#.

Comment: I've updated title - see if it matches your intention. Side note: try to avoid adding  thanks/signatures to posts as they usually don't add much information. Upvote/accept/comment anwsers instead.

Answer (score 2):

That `Memory` class is not part of the C# base class library. It is an example class written for that documentation that illustrates how to use underlying OS memory management functions.

In this example it uses (amonst other functions) `HeapAlloc` and `HeapFree`, which it makes available to C# code using the lines:

```
   [DllImport("kernel32")]
   static extern void* HeapAlloc(int hHeap, int flags, int size);
   [DllImport("kernel32")]
   static extern bool HeapFree(int hHeap, int flags, void* block);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not in one of the libraries. That's just an example. You can copy and paste the code if you want to use it, but I don't see why you'd want to have non-managed memory management in C#.